# How to create a blog post on custom wordpress from a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress

I am having wordpress installed at digitalocean and it is working fine.

I need to create a blog post at custom wordpress site using Ruby on Rails. Can anyone please let me know that, how I can authorize a user and access my wordpress site in order to post an article using ruby on rails?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you rephrase this?  It's unclear what you are asking about.

Comment: I think you might be confused. Wordpress is an out-of-the-box CMS, with blogging/posting abilities in-built. Rails is a web framework, a blank template, which can be used to build a CMS or your own. (Or anything else you can dream up.) You could build a RoR App to interact with WP for you, but why?

Comment: We can post data to facebook/twitter from a RoR application. In the same way, I am trying to do postings at wordpress from RoR application.